# Creating 2d grid from laser scans

Tags: gazebo, kinect, rviz, turtlebot, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to create an OccupancyGrid without using the 2D SLAM libraries? I have a turtlebot firing laser scans while rotating - the lasers collide into the rooms walls.  I want to create an OccupancyGrid showing where there are empty spaces and obstacles.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28833/creating-2d-grid-from-laser-scans./) by [AmaneSuzuha](https://answers.ros.org/users/1879/amanesuzuha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Costmap_2d package in navigation stack shall satisfy your requirements.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0